# Unable to read HTTP headers in an API resource

Tags: api, logging, http-headers, wso2, esb

I am trying to read HTTP header from inside an API that I defined in the ESB. I have tried various methods (see below) all of them print out "null" in the logs.

```
<log level="custom"> 
    <property name="LOG-POSITION___________________________" value="...4"/>
    <property name="AXIS2___________________________" expression="$axis2:accept"/>
    <property name="AXIS2___________________________" expression="$axis2:Accept"/> 
    <property name="AXIS2___________________________" expression="$axis2:ACCEPT"/> 
    <property name="CTX___________________________" expression="$ctx:accept"/> 
    <property name="CTX___________________________" expression="$ctx:Accept"/> 
    <property name="CTX___________________________" expression="$ctx:ACCEPT"/> 
    <property name="TRP___________________________" expression="$trp:accept"/> 
    <property name="TRP___________________________" expression="$trp:Accept"/> 
    <property name="TRP___________________________" expression="$trp:ACCEPT"/> 
</log>
```

I can't see why it is not working.

Comment: expression="$trp:Accept" should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the synapse code to read and log the content-type http header. Here `$trp` stands for the transport header.

```
<log level="custom">
     <property name="Content_Type" expression="$trp:Content-Type"/>
</log>
```

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Synapse+XPath+Variables

If it doesn't work, [enable wire logs](http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html) and post the logs in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to this by looking through existing code, and doing a bit of trial and error.

The expression "$trp:Accept" works, but it must be used before using either a call or send mediator.

For any others experiencing this issue, move the property mediator for grabbing this to the beginning of your proxy or api and the values should come through.

Comment: Yes, after call and send mediators, older headers are replaced by the new ones in the new response.